# find property inside nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, notion

I have an object that contains data to display information pulled from the Notion API. I can see the data but not sure how I can extract nested array inside the current array. My goal is to use the category property to create a filter but first I need to get the string to create the condition.

Here is what the data looks like currently. How would I go about to filter out `name: "commissions"`:

```
resultsArray:
  0:
      properties
      category:
        id: "sdasd"
        multi_select:
          0:
              id:"324234"
              name: "commissions"
```

I have tried use find but it doesn't do what I expect. My suspicion is that I will have to loop over the nested array again.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, give credit to the person who gave the answer and give them a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find inside find condition

like this :

```
data.resultsArray.find(item=>item.category.multi_select.find(select=> select.name === "commissions"))
```

```js
const data = {
  resultsArray: [
    {
      category: {
        id: 'sdasd',
        multi_select: [
          {
            id: '324234',
            name: 'commissions',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};

const result = data.resultsArray.find(item=>item.category.multi_select.find(select=> select.name === "commissions"))

console.log(result)
```